# Can I add a password for SQL Server "sysadmin" role?

Tags: sql-server

I need help in adding password to SQL server role. Actually I'm working on SQL server and Sybase ASE. In Sybase I can add a password for SA_ROLE & SSO_Role. Can I do the same in SQL Server?

Thanks in advance,
Ramez Nabil

Answer (score 1):

Typical SQL Server roles do not have passwords associated with them. A SQL login has a password, and that SQL login is then assigned to a role.

(There is a mechanism with SQL called an Application Role. That type of role has a password associated with it, but I don't think that's what you are asking about.)